# Stored procedure's where clause parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below scenario:

```
----------------
ID    |    Type
----------------
1     |    AB
2     |    CD
3     |    EF
```

Now, the query I need for this query in stored procedure is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE TYPE IN ('AB','CD','EF')
```

I have written the below procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_get_all
  @Type    VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE TYPE IN (@Type)
END
```

This query is working fine only when I am calling it in the below way:

```
EXEC usp_get_all 'AB'
```

Now, there may be a situation like below, which is not working

```
EXEC usp_get_all '''AB'',''CD'',''EF'''
```

My question:

I don't want to use any function to split the comma separated input parameters. Only by using the input parameter I want to get the same result like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE TYPE IN ('AB','CD','EF')
```

Is there any way that can do the trick? Can I use dynamic SQL? If I can, how can I use that in this case?

Comment: somethin like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024219/conversion-failed-in-cursor-in-stored-procedure/15038078#15038078

Comment: Do you understand that there is a logical difference between a single string parameter that may happen to contain `'` and `,` characters, and multiple string parameters, separated by commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc (@typy NVARCHAR(299))
AS

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL='SELECT * from table_name where typ in ('+@typy+')'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

And then execute:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [myProc]
        @typy = N'''AB'',''BC'''
```