# Database import from text/csv file and many to many relationship

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-migration

I have a Windows SQL Server database with a many-to-many relationship between some articles and categories, the relation is made by an `ArticleCategorie` table with two columns => `[ArticleID] - [CategorieID]`.

The problem now is that I have a csv file which look like this (*picture) with two columns article id and article tags (let's say the article id is 5; and that it has 4 different categories which has respectively id 1,4,6 and 7) so here is how the CSV looks like =>

```
   |ArticleID----|Article Categories---|
   |5------------|1,4,6,7--------------|
```

*Picture :

[image]

The best way I found was to manually add to the table all data (articles + categories) like this :

[image: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2h4x2s6.jpg]

So this is above the final result that I want.  Unfortunately I have more than seven hundreds articles, and can't find any faster way to import them, any solutions ? How can I import my data in a fast way? Maybe I could go for a better database design ?

Comment: You could use one of the various [Split](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16993267/1699210)  routines that can be found on this side

Answer (score 0):

Its not an elegant solution but it works. Import the data from the csv file to a temporary table using `openrowset` or import data. Then run the following code

```
declare @aid varchar(88)
declare @cid varchar(88)
declare @cur as cursor
SET @cur = CURSOR FOR(SELECT * FROM temp)
open @cur
FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @aid,@cid
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
insert into article select @aid,value from dbo.Split(',',@cid)
FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @aid,@cid
END
CLOSE @cur
DEALLOCATE @cur
```

Here is the code for the `split()` function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep char(1), @s varchar(5120))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
WITH pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
UNION ALL
SELECT
pn + 1,
stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
FROM pieces
WHERE stop > 0
)
SELECT pn,
SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 5120 END) AS Value
FROM pieces
)
```